# Помогите распарсить attachments в wall.get

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Вызываю все так:

```
    VKRequest reqWall = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, группа, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100, "text"));
                        reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
                        reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                                super.onComplete(response);

                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                                String owner = null;
String audio = null, video = null, poll = null;
                                try {
                                    owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                posts = new VKPostArray();
                                try {
                                    posts.parse(response.json);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                             try {
                                JSONArray attachments = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("attachments"));
                                JSONObject xx = (JSONObject) attachments.get(0);
                                audio = xx.getJSONObject("audio").getString("url");
                                video = xx.getJSONObject("video").getString("mp4_360");
                                poll = xx.getJSONObject("poll").getString("answer");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                try {
                                    VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }
```

Много чего парситься вопросов нет, но не могу распарсить к примеру во вложениях VkApiPoll.answers и к примеру VkApiVideo mp4_360 ( приходит null)... помогите распарсить attachment в методе wall.get, ато вообще ни когда не имел дел с этим json

Comment: JSONArray attachments добавил, вот только храбрости мне это не придало(

Comment: по моему вы приложили не полный код. у вас не возникают исключения на этапе разбора?  например, если в этой строчке `JSONObject xx = (JSONObject) attachments.get(0);` возникнет исключение, то переменные `audio, video, poll` останутся `null`

Comment: Именно...потому что я незнаю как ибо с json никогда не работал...помогите исправить?

Comment: Просто я не понимаю как в этом коде attachments влияет на posts?? Никак не дорубаю как posts заставить парсить вложения?

Comment: Вообще зачем вам какой-то JSON? там же можно использовать методы `reqWall.getItems().get(0).getAttachments().get(0).` и т.д. разве нет? вы когда после точки пишите `get...` вам IDE ничего не подсказывает?